# Python library files in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I would like to import all of my python files into Robot framework. Currently, I am referencing the files with their entire paths. Instead of that, is there any way to call all the required files in one line? Perhaps by importing all library paths in Robot framework.

Here is an example...

My python scripts are in these locations..

```
/user/home/scriptLibrary/sample.py
/user/home/scriptLibrary/sample_1.py
```

and I want to import all python files in Robot script. I am currently hard coding the entire path in the beginning of the script.

```
/user/home/scriptLibrary/sample.py
/user/home/scriptLibrary/sample_1.py
.
.
.
/user/home/scriptLibrary/sample_n.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Robot doesn't support more than one library per line in a Settings table. However, you can create a keyword that loads the libraries, then call the keyword from a suite setup. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Suite Setup | Import all libraries

*** Keywords ***
| Import all libraries
| | Import library | ${CURDIR}/sample.py
| | Import library | ${CURDIR}/sample_1.py
| | Import library | ${CURDIR}/sample_2.py
...
| | Import library | ${CURDIR}/sample_n.py
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. It's very difficult to import each and every file. If there is no other alternative I will go with this options.

Comment: @siya: Were you looking for a way to load everything in a folder? You could write a keyword that gets a list of files and import them all. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi,I am looking for importing option. lets say all my library files in one directory. I just want to import in robot script like.. Import Lib *. So that in other Robot files also I can import lib files in one line "Import Lib *"

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing all of these imports in a resource file if they are used together. Then in each suite, you only need to import the resource to import all the libraries.

Comment: Actually, I will be using same libraries for all of my robot scripts. So,  I am looking for, if we can make all these lib files into one package and calling it in Robot script.